# How to install PHP 5.5 on WinXp

Tags: php

I downloaded the 5.5.4 x86 VC11 version of PHP. The windows installer is missing, since PHP developers don't produce anymore it. 
I need just the PHP console, I don't need Apache, but I can't launch the PHP binary since I get **"not a valid Win32 application"** error. I already installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 library, what is missing?

Comment: @DontVote - maybe MaxV is just running something on the console?

Comment: Yes, I need just PHP console.

Comment: Use XAMPP, (with php 5.4 or 5.5, mysql, apache)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Why should someone need apache for php? While php can be used just for scripting/automation purpose (not generating a website) there are also other webservers, and even php itself has an build in (experimental) webserver.

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded the x86 and not the x64 version?

Comment: Yes, double checked! I tried also php-5.5.5-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip with the same result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since PHP 5.5

> Support for Windows XP and 2003 has been dropped. Windows builds of PHP now require Windows Vista or newer.

Official sources: [backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.incompatible.php), [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.0), [first alpha release notes](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.0alpha1/NEWS), [breaking commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/94994104a54a57ee3ff2a143a1f6c43850589378).

---

**But** there is an unofficial build of PHP 5.6 at http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6334

Comment: There is a good way to get a compatible OLD release like PHP 5.4 x86
From http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS in windows XP to create an local server in your pc

- get reference on installing IIS [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/iiiisin2.mspx)
- then download an install php msi for iis you can get latest available
  version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpinstallermsi/files/)
- And last download this small IIS plugin "PHP Manager" from [here](http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/releases/view/69115)

Comment: I don't need a web server, just the PHP script language. With PHP 5.3.5 all was working perfectly. Now that PHP doesn't have an installer, I can't work with PHP anymore... :-(